# Rails disable remote form submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a form that I want to submit through AJAX most of the time. However, there's also multiple file fields in the form. Whenever a file is submitted I need to temporarily disable AJAX-functionality so that the file can be processed.

I tried removing the data-remote attribute, but of course that's not enough because jQuery already binds the AJAX function to the form. How do I unbind it?

Edit:

Oh wow, I'm so stupid. Rails does this by default. I hadn't even tried it yet. Sorry for polluting StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow, Rails does this by default. I hadn't even tried it yet. Sorry for polluting StackExchange.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you simply remove the data-remote attribute.  If you are using jquery it would look something like this:

```
$("#element").removeAttr("data-remote");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use :disable_with option like

```
<%= submit_tag 'Submit', :disable_with => 'Please wait..' %>
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I do not want to disable the form. I want to unbind jQuery's AJAX-function so that the form is posted normally.